# Нужно ограничение по созданию блоков в Js не более 3, а если больше то они просто не появляются

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Вот код:

```
function onClick() {
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var textarea1 = document.getElementById("textarea1");
var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");

var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.className = "div1";
div1.innerHTML = text1.value;

var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.className = "div2";
div2.innerHTML = textarea1.value;

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "divA";
div.appendChild(div1);
div.appendChild(div2);

container.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо просто считать кол-во добавленных div'ов и прерывать функцию если их больше 3.

```js
function onClick() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var textarea1 = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  
  var len = container.querySelectorAll('.divA').length;
  if(len >= 3){ return; }
  
  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.className = "div1";
  div1.innerHTML = text1.value;

  var div2 = document.createElement("div");
  div2.className = "div2";
  div2.innerHTML = textarea1.value;

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "divA";
  div.appendChild(div1);
  div.appendChild(div2);

  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  max-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="textarea1" cols="30" rows="10">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet textarea </textarea>
  <input id="text1" value="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet input"><br>
<button onclick="onClick()">Copy smth</button>
<div id="container">
</div>
```